# How to install pygame in python 2.7.6 on ubuntu 14?

Tags: software-installation, python-2.7

How can I install pygame in python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14? I've used `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`, but it does not work and gives me the following message: `unable to locate package python-pygame`. What shall I do now?

Answer (score 0):

the best way to install python modules in python is 
do

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

and then do

```
sudo pip install name_of_python_module
```

for you

```
sudo pip install pygame
```

and if you are unsure about name of any of the modules
you can do

```
pip search name_of_python_module
```

and it will give you the search results and take the name and install by above method

Comment: this time it gives me this message: unable to locate package python-pip!

Comment: do you have any suggestions why it happens?

Comment: have you enabled universe section in your software and updates..

Comment: or you can install pip from instructions given here https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: yeah, it's enabled... I will check that instruction. thanks for your help.